# How can I set a card to default value if there's no filter? How can I set a default filter to page?

Tags: powerbi

I have this dashboard:

[image: DASHBOARD]

What I want :

1. How can I make it so that when a user enters the dash board, the page is filtered automatically to yesterday's values and the user has the ability to filter what he want using the slicers shown?
2. How can I set a default value to a card so that when the slicer `ID` displays **ALL**, the card has a default value like `company name`.

Comment: You seem to have all the filters set up. All you have to add is select the desired filters in the dashboard and save it before closing. The next time you open the dashboard all these filters would be applied by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> Add report/page level filter with your date field, select type "relative filtering" and set the value to last 1 days and save the report.

2> In the measure, you are using for the card add the following:

```
RETURN 
    IF(
       HASONEVALUE('your company field'),
       SELECTEDVALUE('your company field'),
       "The default value you want"
    )
```